Inheriting Time Machine Backup: Macbook M2 macOS Sequoia
I want to inherit Time machine backup of my old mac that was running Catalina. I tried following this instruction: Inheriting Time Machine Backup: Invalid Target but looks like TMSafetyNet.kext is no longer available in the newer Macs. Any suggestions ?

Your Catalina Time Machine (TM) disk is HFS+ formatted. Sequoia, and other recent macOS versions, use APFS format for the TM disk.  This is a major change.
TMSafetyNet was only for old HFS+ TM.
Start a new TM backup to a new APFS volume.  This is best done with a new external drive. Apple Support has this Back up your Mac with Time Machine to get you started.
Preserve your existing TM disk until you are sure you don't need to recover anything from it.
